# Powershell, look (loop) through all drives

Tags: powershell, loops, recursion

I'm new to Powershell and I've tried finding a solution to my problem online but I can't seem to find one. Basically I need to write something that will let powershell look through all drives and directories to find the following:

total number of files (exclude folders), largest file size, average file size, total file size

Here's what I've written so far:

```
$source = "get-psdrive"

#attempt at looking through all drives/directories which didn't work
foreach($a in $source) {

    #counts files in given directory
    Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force |
        Measure-Object |
        ForEach-Object { $_.Count }

    #select largest file in given directory
    Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force |
        Sort-Object Length -Descending |
        Select-Object -First 1

    #get average file size in a given directory
    Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force |
        Measure-Object -Property Length -Average

    #sum of file sizes in given directory
    (Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force |
        Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum
}
```

The issue is that it only looks in the C drive. I don't know if there's a way to look through my computer instead of specific drives but I couldn't seem to find a way. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: `foreach($a in $source)` -> `foreach($a in & $source)`; to execute a command whose name is stored in a string you must use `&`, the call operator. Also, your `Get-ChildItem` commands don't actually reference `$a`, the drive at hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `"..."` you define a string, so in your example you try to loop over a string.

Try it like this:

```
$Drives = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider 'FileSystem'

foreach($Drive in $drives) {

    #counts files in given directory
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Drive.Root -Recurse -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force |
        Measure-Object |
        ForEach-Object { $_.Count }

    #select largest file in given directory
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Drive.Root -Recurse -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force |
        Sort-Object Length -Descending |
        Select-Object -First 1

    #get average file size in a given directory
    Get-ChildItem -Path $Drive.Root -Recurse -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force |
        Measure-Object -Property Length -Average

    #sum of file sizes in given directory 
    (Get-ChildItem -Path $Drive.Root -Recurse -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force |
        Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum

}
```

Note! I didn't chang your `Get-ChildItem` code (except the path where it will search). I only wrote the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Could make it a bit faster by  feeding the results into a variable, instead of running GCI it 4 times each loop. Something like this:

```
#specify preferred measures
$average_size = "MB"
$individual_size = "GB"
$total_size = "TB"

Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem |ForEach-Object {

    "`n$($_.Root)" |Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan

    $details=$null
    $details = Get-ChildItem -Path $_.Root -Recurse -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force



    "`nFile Count: $('{0:N0}' -f $details.count)" 



    "Average size: "+"$([math]::round(($details |
          Measure-Object -Property Length -Average |select -Property average).average /"1$($average_size)", 2))"+" $($average_size)"

    "Total size: "+"$([math]::round(($details |
          Measure-Object -Property Length -sum |select -Property sum).sum /"1$($total_size)", 2))"+" $($total_size)"


    $details |
        Sort-Object Length -Descending |
        Select-Object -First 5 -Property @{L='Path';E ={$_.fullname}},@{L="Size $($individual_size)";E={[math]::round(($_.length) /"1$($individual_size)", 3)}} |ft

    
}
```

Couldn't stretch it to assign sizes dynamically, but where do you draw the line...