# How do I get list of all the files on a computer using Powershell

Tags: powershell, file-management

Till now I have managed to get all the files in a drive with their path, size in bytes, date modified, date created and file extension. But I can't figure out a way to get files of all the drives in a single csv file.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path E:\ -Recurse |
foreach{
$Item = $_
$Type = $_.Extension
$Path = $_.FullName
$Folder = $_.PSIsContainer
$Age = $_.CreationTime
$Length= $_.Length
$Modified=$_.LastWriteTime

$Path | Select-Object `
    @{n="Name";e={$Item}},`
    @{n="Created";e={$Age}},`
    @{n="filePath";e={$Path}},`
    @{n="Size in Bytes";e={$Length}},`
    @{n="Modified";e={$Modified}},` 
    @{n="Extension";e={if($Folder){"Folder"}else{$Type}}}`
   
}| Export-Csv E:\Results4.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell, look through all drives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44911486/powershell-look-through-all-drives)

Comment: This is actually more tricky than it sounds. Would you like to include or exclude, say, mapped network drives and mounted ISO images, virtual hard disks or mount points?